# How to query the number of used License in salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger

userLicense is the one of the standard object in salesforce. and used License is the one of the label in that object. my question is how to  query the number of  used license in userLicense Object.

Answer (score 3):

You can't query license count in salesforce.

There is an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=0873000000070WrAAI) posted in idea exchange

You could try [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3916/getting-remaining-licenses-of-customer-portal-using-apex) approach

Comment: More info would be great here.

Comment: @mast0r updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

it looks like from the idea, as of summer '17 you can use the UserLicense API to do this. Link [HERE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_userlicense.htm)