# how to create a pop up using VF page?

Tags: popup

I want that after creating User with salesforce license and saving it ,a pop up will come  with the info that how much User license are left .

Comment: Check this and get an idea http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3916/getting-remaining-licenses-of-customer-portal-using-apex

Comment: Are you creating these users through the setup UI or a visualforce page ? Adding more details of your question, and showing what research or coding you have already done will improve the quality of what others can answer you.

Comment: Using Setup UI .Im new to Apex, thats why dont have any code yet .

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating your users through the setup UI, you can't do this I'm afraid.  There's no way to customise those pages and no sidebar to place JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I would say why pop up, because you can easily see number of remaining licenses in Company profile accessible under setup.