# How to find total number of external communities created in the org?

Tags: apex, community

How can I query on the network object to find how many external communities (Partner or Customer) created in the org?

```
Database.Countquery('SELECT Count() FROM Network ');
```

Comment: How do you know from the admin screens if a community is external?

Comment: @identigral as an admin I can create partner portal community so I want to query on the specific types of a community like Partner or Customer

Comment: Could you point to a screen or add a screenshot? We don't have an option in our org to create a "partner portal" community.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [community types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5) based on License which is applied on community.

You can check Portal License information based on user profile which is assigned to Portal Users.

```
//Get profile id    
SELECT id,name,SelfRegProfileId FROM Network
//Get License Id Information
SELECT id,name,UserLicenseId FROM Profile where id='<SelfRegProfileId>'
//Get License Information from Profile
SELECT id,name FROM UserLicense where Id='<UserLicenseId>'
```

You can refer [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3916/getting-remaining-licenses-of-customer-portal-using-apex) to get more about License information about your org.

Comment: I actually want to know about is there any object to store information like community type, I noticed in one of my org we don't have any external license so I'm not able to create "partner Central" type community which is disabled.

Comment: I don't think we have specific field in any object to identify community type.